# Unable to resolve 55.0 in Felix, my missing jar is created from "Imported Classes" needed by Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-felix, m2e

this is my first question, go easy on me :)

I'm new working with Eclipse and Maven plugin (M2E)
My project in eclipse used many jar files imported using Maven, however, a few packages came from my organization and are a couple  of .class files which do not have source code.

Investigating on Internet, I did not found an easy way to import class folders to maven projects, so I tried a solution to build a JAR from the class folders and then add the dependency to my generated JAR file and put the JAR file in the ".m2" folder. with this, my project can be build properly and the project JAR can be generated. However, this project jar needs to be loaded in Felix Framework, then, when I put the project jar in Felix, I get the error "Unable to resolve 55.0: missing requirement [55.0] osgi.wiring.package" which I cannot solve, I know this means Felix is not finding this dependency however I've validated the next things:

1. Jar file with the ImportedClasses is inside the bundle folder of Felix
2. Project Jar file can be generated and executed properly with Maven in eclipse and executed in the local environment of the IDE.
3. Felix was used before with other JAR projects and ran properly.

Here is the dependency in my pom.xml

```
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>rea-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>rea-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure if the JAR created with my classes needs to have something in particular in the manifest.mf, currently is almost empty.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. 
Sorry if is not quite clear with the explanation.

Anyone went through something similar or have any suggestion on where can I go from here?

Thank you for reading the long post!

Comment: You have to look at the package name mentioned at the end of the error message (after osgi.wiring.package). Usually, this means you're missing a bundle jar that exports that package. So you either have to add that bundle to the bundle folder, or (if the missing package is in a non-bundle jar) embed the dependency into your own jar.